# Comma exists after creating array in AJAX

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have a problem related to an array data which fetched from an external file. The script used is AJAX ina  `.js` file. After fetching the data from an external file (.php), the array data showed a comma in front of each item. Is there any problem with my code? If there is any way to solve this problem, please do let me know.

Sample code:

```
var i = 1;
var loadPcs = [];
var deststop = [];
var datestop = [];

while (i <= counter)
{
                    
    deststop[i]= encodeURI(document.getElementById('stop'+i).value);
    deststop[i] = deststop[i] + ("%");
    
    datestop[i]= encodeURI(document.getElementById('depDate'+i).value);
    datestop[i] = datestop[i] + ("%");

    notes[i]= encodeURI(document.getElementById('notes'+i).value);
    notes[i] = notes[i] + ("%");

    i = i + 1;  
}

    {

    var stopdest = deststop;
    var stopdate = datestop;

        http.open('get', 'insert.php?&deststop='+stopdest+'&datestop='+stopdate+'&loadPcs='+loadPcs+'&notes='+notes+'&counter='+counter);  
    }
```

Comment: One question : why your array index(var i) starts with 1?

Comment: If possible can you share your php code.It will help us how output is sent.

Comment: Actually it's a normal .php file with a button called [Save]. What happen is, whenever I click on [Save] button, if the var i=1; the data can be pass to the next page, but if I change the var i value to var i = 0; the button will not be functioning anymore.

Comment: If i am not wrong , it seems you want to send array data(notes , loadNo) to insertStop.php?

Comment: Yes exactly, the data can be pass to that page. Unfortunately, each and every data that has been passed contains 1 comma(,) in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Instead of using array take a string variable , take a look at below code

```
var deststop = "";
while(i <= counter)
{
   deststop += encodeURI(document.getElementById('stop'+i).value) + "%" ;
}
```

Replace all arrays with a string variable and append data like done in above code.

Comment: @ Ravi Jain. Thanks. Will do as advice.

Answer (score 1):

you are starting the array index from 1

```
      var i =1
```

Give the index value as zero

```
      var i=0
```

I think it is taking the 1st value as null value hence it is showing the null value and after that a comma .Because in javascript the array wil seperate with a delimiter ",".

Comment: Ok thanks, i have changed var i=0. But nothing happens when I clicked the next button to proceed.

Comment: @aZman Aziz : didn't get you .where your next button ??? you just changed your i value .So what will happen to your next button????